# Change color of text based on cell color in heat map using d3

Tags: d3.js, heatmap

In a heat map I want the color of the text to be a darker color of the cell so that the numbers are visible properly.

Below is a sample image of a cell.

[image]

I have used .darker() but the darker color is not so crisp as this.

```
d3.color(color).darker(3);
```

Below is what I have got.

[image]

How to achieve the same colours using d3.
I tried opacity also but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think it looks fine, though you may want to fiddle with the parameter.  In general,

```
d3.color(color).darker(k)
```

gets "darker" exponentially quickly - like `0.7^k`, in fact. Thus, 3 might be pretty large. I suppose that `k=1.5` looks a bit better.

```js
let color = d3.color("#abebc6")
let darker = d3
  .color(color)
  .darker(1.5);
 let div = d3.select('#container')
  .append('div')
  .style('padding', '5px')
  .style('text-align', 'center')
  .style('background', color)
  .style('color', darker)
  .text(`${color} - ${darker}`)
let input = d3.select('#container')
  .append('input')
input.attr('type','range')
  .attr('min', 0)
  .attr('max', 3)
  .attr('step', 0.01)
  .attr('value', 1)
  .on('input', function() {
    let k = input.property('value');
    let darker = d3.color(color).darker(k);
    div.style('color', darker)
    .text(`k=${k}; ${color} - ${darker}`)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```